# How to prevent Python function from interpreting escape characters in a string?

Tags: python

I have a following Python code:

```
my_str = 'some\100random'


def func(x):
    print(my_str)
    temp_str = repr(x.replace("\\", "/"))
    return temp_str

print(func(my_str))
```

The output of the `print` function inside `func` is `some@random`. Is there way to stop a function from converting `\100` to `@`?

I know I can use a raw string in variable `my_str = r'some\100random'` but the problem is I use this function in our internal program and I don't have access to variable itself. I can only use Python function, which receives a parameter `x` from outside of its scope.

The output I want to receive is `'some/100random'`.

Comment: `\100` _is_ `@`. It's nothing to do with the function, you can `print(my_str)` straight away and see that's what the value is. If you want a literal backslash, it needs escaping - `'some\\100random'`.

Comment: The value your function is receiving **is `'some@random'`**. It's unclear where this is actually coming from, but again the function is **not** interpreting the escape character.

Comment: Thank You for the answer. Maybe my description is not clear. I know that the output of a `print(my_str)` function  representing `\100` as `@` is correct. But is there way to convert  `'some\100random'` (which is printed as `'some@random'`) to `'some/100random'` in function `func()` without modifying my_str variable as raw string?

Comment: `x.replace('@', '/100')`? There is **no such value** as `'some\100random'`, that's just a representation of a string whose fifth character is the ASCII character with octal representation `100`, which is `@`. It's not _"printed as"_ that, it **is that**.

Comment: `\100` is just an example. This should also works for all other characters e.g input string can look like this `my_str = 'some\100ran\tdom\n'`. I know I can "hardcode" it but maybe there is more efficent way.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide some useful context. As stated, this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Karol any `\100` in a literal in the source code has been converted to `@` before it entered your function. To draw a loose analogy, imagine you wrote a function `f(x)` that had a single integer as a parameter. If your function receives a parameter x=4, you have no way of knowing whether the caller did `f(2+2)`, `f(1+3)`, `f(math.sqrt(16))` ... you just know that you received `4`.

Comment: @Karol Again: As soon as the assignment has happened (`my_str = 'some\100ran\tdom\n'`), the conversion is done. The content of the string referenced as `my_str` is not distinguishable from a string defined in another way, e. g. `my_str = 'some\x40ran\11dom\x0A'`

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> my_str = 'some\100random'
> ```

> Is there way to stop a function from converting \100 to @?

It does not do so.

When you do `my_str = 'some\100random'`, the `\100` is already converted to `@`.

If you want to do this replacement in the scenario you describe, you can either do

```
temp_str = repr(x.replace("@", "/100"))
```

or you can have a list of characters with which you do the replacement:

```
TO_BE_REPLACED = '@=$"'

def replace(c):
    """Replace a character with its octal representation"""
    if c in TO_BE_REPLACED:
        return '/%o' % ord(c) 
    else:
        return c

def func(x):
    # print(x)
    temp_str = repr("".join(replace(i) for i in x))
    return temp_str

my_str = 'some\100random'

print(func(my_str))
```

But that will not bring back the original definition of that string, so it is not very useful, probably.

Comment: Can You explain this code? What is ord() function?

Comment: @Karol The python documentation will be able to explain it better than I can, but it will give you the character code of the character you pass to it. `ord('@')`= 64, and this 64 is converted to octal (100), prepended by a `/`. It will not bring back the original definition of the string (nothing can do that, as you have learned from the comments), but it will do what you asked for.

Comment: @Karol [read the fine manual](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord).